# Router disconnects wifi during upload

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, router, internet, home-networking

I have a problem with my router.

Whenever I upload anything bigger than few mb it disconnects both my and my girlfriend notebooks. I tried to install some older and newer drivers but it didn't help. I've also upgraded firmware of my router, still no change. Problem occurs only when I upload anything from my laptop (windows 10, killer network card), only while using wifi, no problem on cable or when I test it from the other laptop (windows 8.1).

Router name - Tp link WR841N
Laptop - msi GT72 6QD
Network card - killer 1535 wireless network adapter
wifi is set to wpa2 aes

Comment: Just a hunch, if you have original WPA (with TKIP) enabled on the router, try switching to pure WPA2 (AES-CCMP only, no TKIP).

Comment: What's the model of your laptop? What is the "killer network card" model?

Comment: On the router i have WPA2 PSK

Laptop - msi GT72 6QD
Network card - killer 1535 wireless network adapter

Comment: Well bump? still situations without any change